# virtualenv not pointing to local executables

Tags: python, virtualenv

I've noticed strange behavior of virtualenv installed on my local machine. This is what I've been doing:

```
tomasz@laptop:~/Development/Python$ virtualenv nac-env
New python executable in nac-env/bin/python
Installing Setuptools...................................................................................................................................................................................................................................done.
Installing Pip.....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................done.
tomasz@laptop:~/Development/Python$ cd nac-env
tomasz@laptop:~/Development/Python/nac-env$ source ./bin/activate
(nac-env)tomasz@laptop:~/Development/Python/nac-env$ which python
/usr/bin/python
(nac-env)tomasz@laptop:~/Development/Python/nac-env$ which pip
/usr/bin/pip
(nac-env)tomasz@laptop:~/Development/Python/nac-env$ which easy_install
/usr/local/bin/easy_install
(nac-env)tomasz@laptop:~/Development/Python/nac-env$ echo $PYTHONPATH
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
(nac-env)tomasz@laptop:~/Development/Python/nac-env$ deactivate
tomasz@laptop:~/Development/Python/nac-env$
```

As the nettuts screencast says (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IX-v6yvGYFg, 6:55), `python`, `pip` and `easy_install` executables should point to files inside the virtual environment and **not** to `/usr/bin/...` stuff. If the `$PYTHONPATH` sysvar is set incorrectly, I think that my installation doesn't work as expected... Does anyone know what's going wrong?

PS I have installed virtualenv globally on my local machine some time ago. Probably it was intalled through `pip` or sth like that.

Comment: How did you install virtualenv? This isn't normal behavior. Perhaps, reinstall with system's python or pip?

Comment: @VooDooNOFX don't remember how I did it, but your suggetsion was right. After reinstall, everything works fine, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I made myself sure this behavior I had in fact is not normal. I've uninstalled existing `virtualenv` and re-installed it from `pip` and now everything works perfectly:

```
tomasz@laptop:~/Development/Python/foo$ source bin/activate
(foo)tomasz@laptop:~/Development/Python/foo$ which python
/home/tomasz/Development/Python/foo/bin/python
(foo)tomasz@laptop:~/Development/Python/foo$ which pip
/home/tomasz/Development/Python/foo/bin/pip
(foo)tomasz@laptop:~/Development/Python/foo$ which easy_install
/home/tomasz/Development/Python/foo/bin/easy_install
(foo)tomasz@laptop:~/Development/Python/foo$ echo $PYTHONPATH
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this happen to me. Did you change your project path?

When I first created the virtual environment, I used `~/src/my_project/venv` but later changed it to `~/projects/my_project/venv`.  When I ran the activate scripts, it was using the old path.  To fix this, I did a substitution on all of the scripts in the activate directory with the new path and `python`, `pip`, etc. were now sourced from the virtual environment.